# after reinstall ubuntu 12.04 stuck after login screen (not at login screen) showing colourful screen?

Tags: 12.04

How I can fix stuck problem of Ubuntu 12.04 after login I am able to boot windows successfully? then what is problem in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem also and i noticed it was a problem with the graphics card because after that i installed Ubuntu Server and it installed perfectly fine without a problem. But i would also advise you to check if you are installing the correct version